# Is there a site for Personal Habits?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

Is there a site to discuss personal habits and how to fix them?

Also might be about how to change your personality.

Comment: I think the site you're looking for was [closed down](https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity) :P